# Can I use Stripe with custom backend code on Shopify?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, shopify

I have a website on the shopify platform. I want to integrate Stripe into but with some custom logic which, if it was a normal website, would require backend coding. In this particular case it can be achieved by a means of the stripe standard library for javascript or any other language, maybe even via on a client via the Stripe javascript library, but it's not for sure yet.

And since my website uses shopify platform completely and thus has limitions on where I have access to, is it possible to use Stripe in the way described above?

Note, that I need a custom solution which I want to customize myself in a way I wish, I don't want third-party solutions offering Stripe for Shopify.

Comment: This is definitly a question which you should ask the Shopify Support Team and not the Stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead. Using Stripe as you wish is your right to do. You have no obligation to use Shopify checkout if you can use Stripe. The Stripe JS library is probably fine for your needs.

Comment: the question isn't whether or not I'm permitted to use stripe.

Comment: the question is to add custom code I'd normally add **to backend** if it were a normal website hosted somewhere else.

Comment: You asked "Can I"... and the answer is YES. You get the fun of using Stripe, with Shopify, in your own custom way. I did it years ago, so these days, with the improvements in both Stripe and Shopify, it should be even easier. Have fun. Merry Christmas, and happy holidays.

Comment: How can I add custom logic to the code before I send it to Stripe?

Comment: That question is impossible to answer. Tough luck.

Comment: but you try to.

Comment: am I able to save something into a database?

Comment: Daviiddddd, where are youuuuuuu? lalala.

Comment: I told you you can do whatever you want with Stripe. If you want me to do all the programming, I have a company and I charge by the hour. Your question(s) are so vague.

Comment: You can send a cart to Stripe for example and run  your own logic via an App connected to Stripe. You can then deal with Shopify Orders as something else, like COD, where you mark them as paid only when you're happy with what happened in Stripe...